# Trying to import pyTest in VS code but it is not importing and error is displayed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytest

I am trying to import pytest. I have installed it using both `pip` and `python -m pip`.

But in both the cases I am getting following error:

```
import pytest
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.

pyTest was installed under home-brew where as python script were going under local folder.

I changed the interpreter to homebrew path within VS code and all worked fine post that.

This question can be closed.